# Обход таблицы по вертикали

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то простой способ обойти таблицу по вертикали, сейчас я знаю только такой способ, чтобы пройтись по всем ячейкам:

```js
$('td').each(function(i){
  console.log(this);
});
```

но он ходит по горизонтали. Нужен метод, который ходил бы по вертикали:  [image: вот как схематично это выглядит]

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь, литература или любой другой ресурс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти ответ на этот вопрос, сначала нужно верно задать вопрос. Давайте посмотрим на структуру таблицы в `html`-коде:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Сразу становится ясно, почему по умолчанию `JQuery` реализует именно обход по горизонтали - банально потому, что таблица строится из строк (`<tr>`), которые содержат в себе то или иное количество ячеек. Естественно, что если вы начнете перебирать эти ячейки (`<td>`), то ваш перебор пойдет по горизонтали, строка за строкой.

Соответственно, чтобы решить вашу задачу, вам нужно придумать, как преобразовать структуру ваших данных (по сути - таблицу, а если еще конкретнее - `DOM`-дерево селектора `table`), таким образом, чтобы элементы строились вертикально.

Я бы наметил тут три пути:

1. Найти нужный функционал в `JS/JQuery`.
2. Перестроить таблицу средствами `html`, если таковое возможно.
3. Сначала выгрузить все данные в некую матрицу, которую потом крутить как угодно.

Можете посмотреть ответы на эти вопросы (или попытки ответов) [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681595/javascript-jquery-swap-horizontal-and-vertical-order-of-html-table) или [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918094/html-table-with-vertical-rows).

Но на самом деле, самым простым вариантом было бы изменить саму структуру данных в вашей таблице, изменив ее таким образом, чтобы вашему коду было бы необходимо обходить ее именно что горизонтально.

Comment: Пошел по пути наименьшего сопротивления и сделал следующим, кривым, но рабочим способом. 
`     function walkTableVertical(){
  var theRows = $("[class^='tRow_']").get().reverse(); 
  for (var l = 0; l <= 9; l++) {
   $(theRows).each(function(i){
    console.log($(this)[0].childNodes[l]);
   });
  }
 }`